# Calculate between two sheets excel

Tags: excel

I'm new to excel and I would like some help on this.

I have two spreadsheets. On the first sheet, I enter job information and in the second sheet, there is a list of total number of stocks corresponding to their work ids.

This is what I want to do:

```
Sheet 1:
---------------
A1         B1        C1
Ordered  In stock  Work ID
5          95       ABC

Sheet 2:
--------------
A1              B1
Total Stock   Work ID
 100           ABC
```

In Sheet 1, as the user enters the number of stock ordered [A1], it should subtract from the total stock in Sheet 2 and show the remaining balance in both - cell B1 of Sheet 1 and A1 of Sheet 2.

When the user enters another job of the same work ID, it should subtract from the current total i.e  95 [A1 of Sheet 2]

```
Sheet 1:
    ---------------
    A5         B5        C5
    Ordered  In stock  Work ID
    15         80       ABC

    Sheet 2:
    --------------
    A1              B1
    Total Stock   Work ID
     95*           ABC
```

What would be the best way to do this?

*should become 80.

Comment: didn't understand, sheet1 is being edited and sheet2 computes things based on the edits? or the edits may be made on either of the two sheets?

Comment: you mean that sheet 2 contains the total in stock for each workid?

Comment: @yulkanino, yes sheet1 is being edited and sheet2 computes the total stock based on sheet1. that is, the total stock is initially inputted manually by the user. once sheet1 is edited in which, let's say, 20 stocks are ordered, it should deduct from the total stock in sheet2.

Comment: @ADC sheet2 contains the total stock of each workid but the user can enter multiple jobs for the same workid. so in one job 20 stocks are ordered, in another job 5 stocks are ordered. in sheet2, total number of stocks should automatically be calculated by subtracting the number of stocks ordered in sheet1. hope this makes sense.

Comment: ok, so, next question: what happen to the in stock values of sheet 1 if I add a new order? Should those values remain unchanged?

Comment: This is not the sort of task that Excel is good for. Any problem with the updating of Sheet1 and the stock count in Sheet 2 will be wrong and nothing will ever correct it. If you are handling large numbers of orders I would switch to Access. If you are handling small numbers of orders I might (repeat might) consider using a worksheet change event to run a macro which ran down Sheet1 and recalculated the stock count.

Comment: @TonyDallimore: sure? don't  you think my solution would work? did I miss anything in the OPs question? I would be glad to read your comments and improvement suggestions

Comment: Clever @JMax; your solution is ingenious. +1.  I thought the OP's requirement was beyond what could be achieved with formulae.  VBA is powerful but it is very difficult to keep two versions of the same data in step.  With this solution, Excel will automatically recalculate Sheet 2 every time Sheet 1 is changed so they cannot get out of step.

Comment: @TonyDallimore: thanks! glad you liked it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you cannot do with *formulas only* is giving a first input and getting it changed afterwards.

Thus, you can either use VBA (which you won't like if you are a beginner and don't want to learn too much about it) or try this:

In sheet 2:

```
Col A          Col B     Col C
Initial stock  Work ID   Current Stock
100            ABC       95* (and then 80)
```

In sheet 1:

```
Col A          Col B           Col C
Ordered        In stock        Work ID
5              95* (become 80) ABC
...
15             80              ABC
```

Here are the formulas you can use:

In sheet 2, column C (cell C2 to start then drag and drop):

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!B2:B10, B2, Sheet1!A2:A10)
```

In sheet 1, column B (cell B2 to start then drag and drop):

```
=LOOKUP(B2, Sheet2!B2:B22, Sheet2!C2:C22)
```